# How to install windows media player plugin on chromium?

Tags: chromium, multimedia, plugins

There is a website that streams local TV and it requires windows media player plugin. I have LUbuntu freshly installed, but it simply says "Missing Plug-in". It doesn't say anything about what packages I need to install. What's the right package/s to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've got it working now. I have removed the packages from Medibuntu PPA (since I don't require its packages yet) and installed these packages:

- [totem-mozilla](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/totem-mozilla)
- [gstreamer0.10-alsa](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-alsa)
- [gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg)
- [gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3)
- [gstreamer0.10-nice](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-nice)
- [gstreamer0.10-pitfdll](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-pitfdll)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-base](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-base)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-good](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-good)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly)
- [gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse)
- [gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio)
- [gstreamer0.10-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-tools)
- [gstreamer0.10-x](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-x)
- [flashplugin-installer](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/flashplugin-installer)

These are taken from the package list from my previous Ubuntu (thanks to dv3500ea for the clues). I am not sure if there are any packages that are safe to remove. I forgot the forum thread in which I followed the guide. I also have VLC plugin (mozilla-plugin-vlc) installed but it's not necessary to play the video. I still have it enabled and the video is playing.

Answer (score 1):

With current versions of Chromium this is no longer possible.  Chrome and Chromium have abandoned support for NPAPI plugins which include Totem, GStreamer, VLC, etc.  Until/unless there is a new PPAPI version of these plugins, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The default video player on Ubuntu (Totem) provides the Windows Media Player plugin. As @Dracirate has said, it may help to disable the VLC plugin. Your about:plugins page should look something like this:

[image: about:plugins]

Comment: My about:plugins is almost the same as of yours now except Totem is v2.32.0. I have installed Medibuntu and other gstreamer packages but I have only played the "Live Video". The "Video on Demand" won't play; it's just blank screen. Any clue on how to determine the right packages needed?

Comment: Found out that flash player was the only last piece missing.

Answer (score -1):

By any chance are you using VLC? If you do

Disable the VLC Multimedia Plug-in in about:plugins

Comment: I just want it to play on the browser, chromium.

Comment: Disable the VLC Multimedia Plug-in in about:plugins

Comment: I don't have the VLC plugin installed a while ago. I tried to install it and nothing new.

Comment: check your about:plugins ? if you have the plugin enable

Answer (score -3):

I would look at the possibility of using wine to install Internet explorer and Windows media player. Take a look at `winetricks`for more information.

there is also the possibility that he may need to use MS SilverLight. There is an open source alternative called `Moonlight` that is available for ubuntu.

Comment: As much as possible I would like to stay away from wine. I have it working without wine.