# what plugin is required to hear audio on this page

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, plugins, multimedia, media

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52
on following page 
http://swargarohan.org/ramcharitmanas/bal-kand/

there are audios

```
Ramcharitmanas - Bal Kand : Mukesh 
Ramcharitmanas - Bal Kand : Anup Jalota
```

I have flash installed and vlc etc but upon hitting the above site the audios do not play and some missing plugin kind of screen is displayed.Which plugin in required here?

Answer (score 0):

It need Windows media player Plug-in 10, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6051/how-to-install-windows-media-player-plugin-on-chromium) is a post on how to install it. Also my chromium had it already installed, I just entered `chrome://plugins` and Enabled it.