# how to play video on www.mbcradio.tv on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: plugins

can't play video from www.mbcradio.tv. ask for plug-in. can't find the plug in listed.Please help me how to play video from this site.

Comment: Which plugin? What browser are you using?

Comment: I just checked it the website is asking for Windows Media Player plug-in.

Comment: That website requires `Windows media player` and you can install that, please see this answer =>    http://askubuntu.com/questions/6051/how-to-install-windows-media-player-plugin-on-chromium

Answer (score 0):

this problem not that much related to Ubuntu actually but I'll help you out with Mozilla Firefox Browser the default one.

1. Open browser
2. Navigate to `Tools/Add-ons` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. Then go to `Plugins` and at the bottom you must see `Windows Media Player plug-in` and next to him it says `Ask to Activate` change it to `Always Activate` done!

Comment: It does not work. www.mbcradio.tv asks for mms plugins  gstreamer it fails to install,there are missing items in packages. How to solve this?

Comment: it works I checked it myself. Probably your issue is mixed with something else, you need then to paraphrase your question. Did you install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and so on? there can be a lot of different issues.